# Android AsyncTask does not end

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My AsyncTasks are used to call web services. Five, to be exactly. Each AsyncTask starts when the last one finishes.

The AsyncTasks I have all work correctly, but sometimes the AsyncTask does not end. It keeps going forever. It seems to be related with the device going idle/locked but I can't confirm it precisely.

LogCat Shows no error.

I think it may be related either to the AsyncTask statement or the HttpCLient Statement. So I'll leave both here:

```
//http client onCreate()

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

//AsyncTask declaration:

private class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { 
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

              //handles the webservice (with DOM)


            return null;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  

            pd.dismiss();

             //starts next Activity

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          pd = ProgressDialog.show(MenuPrincipal.this,  "", "Refreshing", true);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      }
}
```

Comment: We can't really do much with that. Do you have a forever loop somewhere?

Comment: Print a Log before return statement then you can understand that the doInBackground() exists any forever loop or not.

Comment: try to call webservices like that `asyncTask task = new  asyncTask();
      task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);`

Comment: I dont have a forever loop anywhere. That would make the problem occur every single time. It just occurs once in a while.

@Nayra I will be trying this. it might take some time to see if that worked out or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have tried HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeout) ?  ConnectionTimout is a timeout to connect to your WebService and SoTimeout is to waiting a answare.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will be trying this. it might take some time to see if that worked out or not